# Unable to use Event Viewer without admin permissions

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, event-viewer, mmc

I am using `Windows 7` with latest updates installed.
In past I have been able to use `Event Viewer` as normal user.

Now trying to open `Event Viewer` gives this error:

```
MMC cannot open the file C:\Windows\system32\ecentvwr.msc

This may be because the file does not exist, is not an MMC console or was creted by later version of MMC. 
This may also be because you do not have sufficient access right to the file.
```

If I try to open it with `Run as administrator` it works.
Group `Users\mycomputer` have right to read and execute `C:\Windows\system32\eventvwr.msc` and `eventvwr.exe`.

I have tried using solutions given here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/mmc-cannot-open-the-file/9e21c257-b557-429b-b5b0-808511c0126e. But none of those solved my problem.

How could I make `Event Viewer` work as normal user again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to delete cached MMC files in folder `%appdata%\Microsoft\MMC.
After deleting the files`MMC` folder Event Viewer started working again.

Comment: I wish all problems were this quick and easy to find a solution to and fix.